# Trouble with JavaScript OOP

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning about JavaScript object oriented programming and seem to have run into a problem I couldn't figure out by googling so I am gonna try stack-overflow though I rarely ask questions on forums.

Anyway, I ran into an error while playing with functions after trying to convert some old non OOP code into OOP code. Note there are probably more errors than just the one I am asking about so don't trust any of the code below. The error I am getting is an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `fadeInAnimations` of undefined.

Also, all advice to improve this code is really appreciated.

```
let mainSection = {
    msTime : 0,

    fadeInAnimation : ((element, delayTime) => {
        $(element).delay(delayTime).fadeIn(1000)
    }),

    mainPageElements : [`.traninigTimes`, `.registration`, `.trainingFee`].forEach((element) => {
        this.fadeInAnimation.fadeInAnimations(element, this.msTime)
        this.msTime += 1000;
    })
};
```

Comment: You have function called fadeInAnimation, and are calling fadeInAnimations? But the error is telling you that if you are calling x.fadeInAnimations then x is undefined

Comment: Put simply, `this.fadeInAnimation` is undefined. Could you please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the exact problem.

Comment: `fadeInAnimation` is a function, yet you're trying to use it as an object with a `fadeInAnimations` property?

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.fadeInAnimations(element, this.msTime)` ?

Comment: You don’t have a function object instance here, you only have a normal object you created yourself using object notation.  Therefor, `this` likely points to the global window object - and that doesn’t have a method called `fadeInAnimations`. If you need to access the method from outside the context of this object, then that would be `mainSection.fadeInAnimations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The this context is different in the forEach callback. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

In the callback this refers to the callback context.

```
let mainSection = {
    msTime : 0,

    fadeInAnimation : ((element, delayTime) => {
        $(element).delay(delayTime).fadeIn(1000)
    }),

    mainPageElements : [`.traninigTimes`, `.registration`, `.trainingFee`].forEach(((element) => {
        this.fadeInAnimation.fadeInAnimations(element, this.msTime)
        this.msTime += 1000;
    }).bind(this))
};
```